# Purchase in app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am a new one for Android development. I am wondering about how to purchase in app.
How to begin this feature ? Is there a documentation or API doc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please be more specific and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Android development website](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html).